# Are O-Powers playthrough specific?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

O-power's seem to take a decent amount of time to level up. So I was wondering if they are saved across all games or if they are playthrough specific. If I start a new game will I have the same O-Powers and upgrades or will I need to find them and level them all up again?

Comment: My guess is that everything's going to be reset if you delete your savegame, O-Powers included. But that's only a guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your O-Powers are playthrough specific. If you start a new game you will start with new O-Powers.

If anybody else wants to elaborate further, I did also notice that my first playthrough I started with only Attack Power and my second play through I started with HP Restoring Power AND Capture Power.

Comment: Was your first playthrough before the Patches? As far as I know, you start out with HP Restoring and Capture Power even before you meet Mr. Bonding.